# Using pyparsing Forward() with multiple rules to find palindromic sequence

Tags: python, context-free-grammar, pyparsing

I am trying to find palindromic sequences within DNA by using recursion. I am doing this because it is impossible to know the exact length of a palindromic sequence within DNA. I have worked through the problem in my head and on paper, but the code below still does not come up with the answer I want it to. I am new to pyparsing and using CFGs. Therefore, I might be wrong with the way I set the code up. Any help would be welcome.

```
stem = Forward()
atRule = Word("A") + ZeroOrMore(stem) + Word("T")
taRule = Word("T") + ZeroOrMore(stem) + Word("A")
gcRule = Word("G") + ZeroOrMore(stem) + Word("C")
cgRule = Word("C") + ZeroOrMore(stem) + Word("G")
stem << locatedExpr(Combine(atRule + taRule + gcRule + cgRule))
print(stem.parseString("AAAGGGCCCTTTAAAGGGCCCTTT"))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this style of palindrome - does DNA analysis use a different definition? In other fields, a palindrome is a word or sentence whose letters are the same if the entire string is reversed. In your sample, the only palindromes are the groups "AAA", "GGG", "CCC", etc., which are actually rather degenerate as palindromes go. (I would have expected something like "AAGAACCCCGGTTGGCCCCAAGAA", which reads the same forwards and backwards.)  Also, why are you using `locatedExpr`? It does not change the matching logic, only annotates it with the match start/end locations.

Comment: "*The meaning of palindrome in the context of genetics is slightly different from the definition used for words and sentences*" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_sequence

Comment: @user, your example code is incomplete. Can you produce a short, complete, standalone program that demonstrates the error? See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I was only using locatedExpr as a means of debugging.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire - Ref: my answer, is there a way to force a greedy match? That is, if a language matches both a string and an initial substring, can I force the longer string?

Comment: I looked at this question a bit last night, and ran into the same issue. This may be a fundamental issue with pyparsing's left-to-right parsing, that it is good once it finds a match. There might be a way to say that your palindrome is not a match if do a lookahead, using either `~FollowedBy` or a parse action, and find a palindrome and the genetic reverse of the current pattern - that is you have not found the complete palindrome if what you have is followed by a palindrome and the string that, with the current match would make a complete palindrome. But I expect that this will be slooooowww.

Comment: Essentially, you are implementing in the parser the same heuristic you are doing yourself. How do you know that what you have matched is not the complete palindrome? You probably looked ahead for the genetic reverse of the current one, found it, and then checked if the intervening characters were themselves a palindrome. We just need to put that into your parser in such a way that if the lookahead succeeds (that is, there is more palindrome to be found), then the left-side part of the palindrome parser will keep building up. Again, I can't see this happening with any kind of speed, tho.

Comment: Made progress on the greedy match, see my posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about a few things. Even so, I can't get any parser to match the longest possible palindrome, which I think is your goal.

First, `Word("A")` matches one or more A's. Similarly `Word("T")` matches one or more T's. So:  AAAAT would be matched as a palindrome. Instead, let's do `Literal("A") + ... + Literal("T")`

Second, `ZeroOrMore(stem)` means that you could have multiple interior palindromes. That would match: "A AT TA T", which is not a palindrome. Instead, let's do `Optional(stem)`.

Third, the `+` operator represents concatenation, not alternation. `atRule + taRule + gcRule + cgRule` means "an AT palindrome followed by a TA palindrome, followed by a GC palindrome, followed by a CG palindrome." Instead, let's use `|`.

Fourth, you call `locatedExpr`, with must be newer than my copy of pyparsing. I have included it, and I changed its use slightly.

Here is the modified program:

```
from pyparsing import *

def locatedExpr(expr):
    locator = Empty().setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: l)
    return Group(locator("locn_start") + expr("value") + locator.copy().leaveWhitespace()("locn_end"))

stem = Forward()
atRule = Literal("A") + Optional(stem) + Literal("T")
taRule = Literal("T") + Optional(stem) + Literal("A")
gcRule = Literal("G") + Optional(stem) + Literal("C")
cgRule = Literal("C") + Optional(stem) + Literal("G")
stem << Combine(atRule | taRule | gcRule | cgRule)
lstem = locatedExpr(stem)
print(lstem.parseString('AT'))
print(lstem.parseString('ATAT'))
print(lstem.parseString("AAAGGGCCCTTTAAAGGGCCCTTT"))
```

Here is the result:

```
[[0, 'AT', 2]]
[[0, 'AT', 2]]
[[0, 'AAAGGGCCCTTT', 12]]
```

Notice that result is the minimal initial palindrome, and not the entire string. While I don't think this is your goal, I hope my changes get you closer.

EDIT:

If your goal is to determine if a string is a palindrome (contrasted with "search for a palindrome in a larger string"), then this program might be much easier to use:

```
def DNA_complement(s):
    d = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
    return ''.join(d.get(ch,'') for ch in s)

def DNA_reversed_complement(s):
    return DNA_complement(reversed(s))

def DNA_palindrome(s):
    return s == DNA_reversed_complement(s)

print DNA_palindrome('AT')
print DNA_palindrome('ATAT')
print DNA_palindrome('AAAGGGCCCTTTAAAGGGCCCTTT')
```

Comment: your changes do bring me closer to a final answer and you are write in saying that I want to match the entire string. Thank you very much. If you could also explain to me what the def locatedExpr(expr): is doing, that would awesome. I am new to pyparsing, so I have not used some of those classes and methods.

Comment: My copy (pyparsing 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04) of the pyparsing module was missing the official version of `locatedExpr`, so I had to steal it from [the original sources](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-pysrc.html#locatedExpr). Since you already get `locatedExpr` from the `pyparsing` module, you can ignore my definition.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this problem a bit more, I realized that you really can't know if you have found the longest palindrome unless you start with the entire string, and keep chopping off the end until you either find a palindrome or have no more string left.

```
# sample is a bit longer then the original, I added
# some other characters to the beginning of the string
sample = "AATTAAAAAGGGCCCTTTAAAGGGCCCTTTAAAGGGCCCTTT"

nucleotide_map = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C':'G'}

# simple function to test if a string is a palindrome
def is_palindrome(st, start, end):

    # unlike conventional palindromes, genetic 
    # palindromes must be of even length
    if (end <= start) or ((end-start) % 2 == 0):
        return False

    s,e = start,end
    while e > s:
        if nucleotide_map[st[s]] != st[e]:
            return False
        s += 1
        e -= 1

    return True


def find_longest_palindrome(st, loc):
    s,e = loc, len(st)-1
    while e > s:
        if is_palindrome(st, s, e):
            return st[s:e+1], e+1
        e -= 1
    return '',loc
```

Now finding the palindromes in `sample` is just:

```
loc = 0
FIND_OVERLAPPING = False
while loc <= len(sample):
    pal, tmploc = find_longest_palindrome(sample, loc)
    if pal:
        print(pal, loc, len(pal))

        # advance to next location to look for palindromes
        if FIND_OVERLAPPING:
            loc += (tmploc-loc)/2
        else:
            loc = tmploc
    else:
        loc += 1
```

I'm not sure I've got quite the right take on finding overlapping palindromes. Don't want to just increment loc, or you'll just get all the degenerate cases - that is for a palindrome of AAGAATTCTT, you'll also get AGAATTCT, GAATTC, AATT, and AT.

Here is one way to stitch this into a pyparsing parser:

```
from pyparsing import *

def getAllPalindromes(s,loc,t):
    FIND_OVERLAPPING = False
    ret = []

    sample = t[0]
    while loc <= len(sample):
        pal, tmploc = find_longest_palindrome(sample, loc)
        if pal:
            ret.append((pal, loc))

            # advance to next location to look for palindromes
            if FIND_OVERLAPPING:
                loc += (tmploc-loc)/2
            else:
                loc = tmploc
        else:
            loc += 1

    return ret

palin = Word('AGCT').setParseAction(getAllPalindromes)
palin.parseString(sample).pprint()
```

Gives the result:

```
[('AATT', 0), ('AAAGGGCCCTTTAAAGGGCCCTTTAAAGGGCCCTTT', 6)]
```

**EDIT**

I just ran this using 6 worker processes in a multiprocessing version of this script against this FASTA file (http://toxodb.org/common/downloads/Current_Release/Tgondii/fasta/ToxoDB-28_Tgondii_ESTs.fasta), after first processing the FASTA format to convert each wrapped multi-line sequence into a single string. In 147151 sequences, the script found over 1000 palindromes 20 or more nucleotides in length, in 22 minutes. Here are some of the sample palindromes:

```
ATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATAT
CATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATG
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
CCTCGTGCCGAATTCGGCACGAGGCCTCGTGCCGAATTCGGCACGAGG
CTCGTGCCGAATTCGGCACGAGCTCGTGCCGAATTCGGCACGAG
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACTCGAGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
GGCACGAGGCCTCGTGCCGAATTCGGCACGAGGCCTCGTGCC
TTTATATATAAATATTTATATATAAATATTTATATATAAA
```